# How can Spring Security defend against Brute Force?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Spring Security plugin in a Grails application for authentication and authorization.    It is possible for  a user to try and enter their password a countless amount of times. Is there a configuration setting that will apply some sort of defense against a brute force attack. For example, after 10 attempts, not allow the user a login attempt?

Comment: You can certainly customize that by listening to [login events](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is Spring Security does not provide any implementation to protect against brute force attempts against an account.

However, it does provide you with the means to implement your own strategy for protecting against them. Typically you will need to implement a callback on a failed authentication event. What you do from here depends on what the appropriate course of action is for your application. Some applications will simply increment a session variable of failed attempts and once that threshold is reached simply ignore any further attempts.

Other applications may need to persist this information along with the last failed attempt and lock the account by updating the domain instance after a specific number of failed attempts within a time period.

The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/events.html) does a good job of explaining how to do this, but typically you will want to add the event listeners for the spring security core plugin into your `Config.groovy` like such:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    // Handle successful login
}
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    // Handle failed login
    // example of how to obtain the session if you need it
    def request = grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolder.getRequest()
    def session = request.getSession(false)
}
```

Comment: Another quick win is using `bcrypt` and similar algorithms. You choose the 'cost' parameter and that makes it slower to compute each hash. So each user's login is slower by that factor (less than a second) but each hacker hash calculation takes that long too, and it'll significantly affect their throughput. UPDATE: forgot to mention, this is the default in 2.0, so new apps get this automatically

Comment: Probably also want to use an exponential delay, i.e. don't just let them do 3 or 5 or 10 quick attempts and lock, but add a small delay after the 1st and make each one slower than the previous. For a user mistyping it'll be annoying, but for the automated attack it's a big slowdown. Once that's implemented please send the changes in a pull request and I'll add it as an optional feature :)

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I have some fairly robust password policy and login policy extensions written for Spring Security. Would you really like to see them and consider them for adding into the core plugin? I'd have to clean them up a bit and post them on GitHub but they work really nicely (for our needs).

Comment: Sure, if you think others might use them.

Comment: Alright, I will take some time this weekend and get them up on GitHub.

Comment: Any improvement in that exponential delay ... seems very cool.